# .htaccess url rewrite issue for sub url

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

Here is my .htaccess rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It will construct 'public' for all the requests.

After using this it works for good for

site.com/home , site/blog

but while i start to use

site/blog/data

it does not load the css as it is a sub directory

How can i rewrite the url to make this work

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/blog$1 [L]
```

### Update

For the first probablity

i.e., domain.com/blog the css will be site.com/css/style.css

and while in the next probablity

i.e., domain.com/blog/data the css will be site.com/blog/css/style.css

which is expected as site.com/css/style.css for the second probablity also

How can i do this ?

Comment: Can you show us the part of your code where you include the css file?

Comment: The css path will be as css/style.css simply

Comment: Are you using Laravel's asset helper function? because you definitely should

Comment: You mean {{ Form .. }} this one ..? Not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to show me your code I can only guess here...
I suppose the problem's that you include the css file like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

This means the path is relative to the current URL. What you need to do to make it work on every "level" is use an absolute path or at least one that's relative to the site root (domain)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
```

Or just use the Laravel `asset()` function that generates a full url

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}"/>
```

Or even one step further, use `HTML::style()` to generate the full include code

```
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

Comment: {{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }} I got this one,, And its working, And may i know what it does please

Comment: What matters for your problem is that it is calling `asset()` which then generates an absolute path (e.g. `http://example.com/css/style.css`) so it doesn't matter from what URL you are including it.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, And where can i get such things for loading favicon.ico , <img src=""> etc.,

Comment: In general, you can always use the `asset()` function. For including javascript files, there's also `HTML::script()` which works the same as `HTML::style()`

Comment: Yes thanks, +1  I read those in laravel receipe .. :) Pls upvote if my question is valid